# Printing increasing and decreasing numbers using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, printing

I'm trying to make a recursive method that will give me the following result when printing (example with n = 5): 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1. I can easily achieve it the opposite way using this code:

```
    public static void DownUp(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        System.out.print(n +" ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(n +" ");
        DownUp(n - 1);
        System.out.print(n +" ");
    }
}
```

This will give me the result of: 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5, but I can't seem to do it the way I need because of the way recursion works. I can do it using 2 parameters, but for my needs I want to use only 1 parameter. I've searched and found a few similar posts here/other places using ArrayList etc. That's decent, but not something that gives me the result I need. If someone could guide me how to do that, that would be great, p.s, it's not homework. Thanks.

Comment: That's because you want to `print` it. If you were just constructing the string, and then printing it once in the end, it would be easier...

Comment: Can you change return type? Or have a class level variable to hold the top limit?

Comment: @Andrey Tyukin So there is no way to print it the way I described without using a string?

Comment: @clinomaniac Yeah it should be fine I assume.

Comment: If you can have a class level variable, you can store the max in there and pass the number starting 1 and the condition `n==1` becomes `n==max` and the recursive call `DownUp(n - 1)` becomes `DownUp(n + 1)`.

Comment: Or if you can change the return type, then look at Andrey's answer.

Comment: @clinomaniac if its not too much to ask, can you give an example of what you meant and how to use it?

Comment: @clinomaniac regarding the class level variable: yeah, but that's boring, that's using global state to pass an argument to a single function... That's not good OOP :]

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Agreed. But if the method signature cannot be changed then that's the only other option that I can think of.

Comment: @msacco Which approach do you want to use? A global variable (if the method return type cannot be changed) or returning a formed String so the method itself doesn't print the output but returns a string.

Comment: @clinomaniac I can use both of them tbh, using a string probably won't be very good overall for me, but I think that using a global variable is probably even worse, even tho it might give me a better result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a method to set the start value:

```
public static void downUp(int limit) {

    downUp(1, limit);
}

private static void downUp(int value, int limit) {

    if (((2 * limit) - value) ==0 ) { return;}
    if (value > limit) {
        System.out.print((2 * limit) - value);
    } else {
        System.out.print(value);
    }

    downUp(++value, limit);
}
```

Test it with `downUp(5);`

If you do not like this concept, you can encapsulate the method in a class and use a field as incrementing value:

```
class UpDown {

    static int value = 1;

    public static void downUp(int limit) {

        if (((2 * limit) - value) ==0 ) { return;}
        if (value > limit) {
            System.out.print((2 * limit) - value);
        } else {
            System.out.print(value);
        }
        value++;
        downUp(limit);
    }
}
```

Test it with `UpDown.downUp(5);`

Comment: two args, meh :]

Answer (score 1):

Have a placeholder (here, "x") that marks the place in the string you want to insert the result of a recursive call.  Then have a wrapper method that eliminates the placeholder for the final return.

```
/**
 * Removes the " x " + i from the helper's string.
 * E.g. "1 2 3 4 5 x 5 4 3 2 1" -> "1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1".
 */
public static String upDown(int i)
{
    return upDownHelper(i).replace(" x " + i, "");
}

/**
 * Returns a string e.g. "1 2 3 4 5 x 5 4 3 2 1" if i = 5.
 * The "x" marks the spot where, after a recursive call,
 * the method replaces its current "i" value.
 */
private static String upDownHelper(int i) {
    if (i == 1) {
        return "1 x 1";
    } else {
        return upDownHelper(i - 1).replace("x", i + " x " + i);
    }
}
```

This only requires 1 argument.  Testing:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(upDown(i));
}
```

Output:

```
1
1 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: I think @c0der code will be better for me, but its awesome as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it without extra args, without global static vars, and with same `print`-structure as in original question:

```
public class UpDown {
  public static void upDown(int i) {
    class Helper {
      void rec(int j) {
        if (i == j) {
          System.out.print(i);
        } else {
          System.out.print(j + " ");
          rec(j + 1);
          System.out.print(" " + j);
        }
      }
    };
    new Helper().rec(1);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    upDown(5);
  }
}
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

It's not exactly `recursive` though, because the `upDown` never calls itself. The nested `rec` is recursive.

Comment: Thats an interesting solution, but as you said, Im not quite sure if it counts. Thanks a lot anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void increasingDecreasing(int i, int n){
    if(i == n + 1) return;
    System.out.print(i + ", ");
    increasingDecreasing(i + 1, n);
    System.out.print(i + ", ");
}
```

To execute for 5: increasingDecreasing(1, 5);
Easy, simple and recursive. This will work.